# In J2ME, How to re-index records in recordstore after deleting any record

Tags: java-me, rms, recordstore

I am developing a Location-based J2ME app & in that I'm using RMS to store data.

In `RecordStore` when I delete any record, the underlying records doesn't get re-indexed. For example, if I have 5 records & I delete record no.2 then record ids will be {1, 3, 4, 5}. But I want record ids after deletion to be {1, 2, 3, 4}. How should I do this??? Because recordId is playing an important role in my app to retrieve & update the record.

Comment: Approximately **how many** records do you expect to have in your store?  (and how big is each one, in bytes)

Comment: There only 5 records in recordstore & each record size is around 200 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your application logic. ID is just for identification, and not for sorting. Because it is for identification, it must remains the same.

Very often the easiest thing to do is to read and write the whole recordstore at once.

Comment: Ok.... but in my app I am fetching record on the basis of recordid...   so when i delete any in between record from recordstore recordid's sequence get changed.... So there is nothing any way to reindex the recordid....???

Comment: @Rahul, I think what Meier is saying, and what I suggest in my answer, is **not** to delete records, or sort them, by record id.  If you need to, you can add your own id (index) value to each record.  If you create all your records at once, initially, those index values may be equal to the recordId.  But, from that point on, you should operate on the record's internal index values.  Those are the values that may start as {1,2,3,4,5} and become {1,2,3,4} after deleting a record, and re-indexing.  After that, the record id's will no longer match the index values, but you shouldn't care.

Comment: So I think you want to access the records by index (and not by id). For small recordstores, just read the whole recordstore into a vector. Than you can access the records very easy, without taking care of RMS and the RMS-IDs. After you changed the vector, you just empty the recordstore and write the whole vector back in one go.

Answer (score 2):

So, since you've said that your record store is basically small (not that much data), I would recommend simply adding your own custom `id` field to each record.  [As Meier said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317029/119114), the RMS record id is not really meant to be recalculated, and changed, once a record has been created.  So, I would use your own.

If each of your records contain:

```
boolean isMale
int age
String firstName
```

then, I would simply add another field at the **start** of each record:

```
int id
```

It makes your records a little bigger, but not much (4 bytes/record).  If you'll have less than 64k records, then you could also use a `short` for the `id`, and save a couple bytes.

Here's an example ([adapted from this IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-j2me3/)), of reading, writing, and deleting with this kind of record:

```
   private RecordStore _rs;

   // these next two methods are just small optimizations, to allow reading and 
   //  updating the ID field in a record without the overhead of creating a new
   //  stream to call readInt() on.  this assumes the id is a 4 byte int, written
   //  as the first field in each record.

   /** Update one record with a new id field */
   private static final void putIdIntoRecord(int id, byte[] record) {      
      // we assume the first 4 bytes are the id (int)
      record[0] = (byte)(id >> 24);
      record[1] = (byte)(id >> 16);
      record[2] = (byte)(id >> 8);
      record[3] = (byte)id;
   }

   /** Get the id field from one record */
   private static final int getIdFromRecord(byte[] record) {
      // we assume the first 4 bytes are the id (int)
      return ((0xFF & record[0]) << 24) | 
            ((0xFF & record[1]) << 16) | 
            ((0xFF & record[2]) << 8) | 
            (0xFF & record[3]);
   }

   /** delete a record with the given (custom) id, re-indexing records afterwards */
   private void delete(int idToDelete) {     
      try {
         RecordEnumeration enumerator = _rs.enumerateRecords(new IdEqualToFilter(idToDelete), 
               null, false);
         _rs.deleteRecord(enumerator.nextRecordId());

         // now, re-index records after 'idToDelete'
         enumerator = _rs.enumerateRecords(new IdGreaterThanFilter(idToDelete), null, true);
         while (enumerator.hasNextElement()) {
            int recordIdToUpdate = enumerator.nextRecordId();
            byte[] record = _rs.getRecord(recordIdToUpdate);
            // decrement the id by 1
            int newId = getIdFromRecord(record) - 1;
            // copy the new id back into the record
            putIdIntoRecord(newId, record);
            // update the record, which now has a lower id, in the store
            _rs.setRecord(recordIdToUpdate, record, 0, record.length);
         }
      } catch (RecordStoreNotOpenException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvalidRecordIDException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (RecordStoreException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }               
   }

   /** generate some record store data ... example of writing to store */
   public void writeTestData()
   {
      // just put 20 random records into the record store
      boolean[] booleans = new boolean[20];
      int[] integers = new int[20];
      String[] strings = new String[20];
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         booleans[i] = (i % 2 == 1);
         integers[i] = i * 2;
         strings[i] = "string-" + i;
      }

      writeRecords(booleans, integers, strings);
   }

   /** take the supplied arrays of data, and save a record for each array index */
   public void writeRecords(boolean[] bData, int[] iData, String[] sData)
   {
      try
      {
         // Write data into an internal byte array
         ByteArrayOutputStream strmBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

         // Write Java data types into the above byte array
         DataOutputStream strmDataType = new DataOutputStream(strmBytes);

         byte[] record;

         for (int i = 0; i < sData.length; i++)
         {
            // Write Java data types
            strmDataType.writeInt(i);               // this will be the ID field!
            strmDataType.writeBoolean(bData[i]);
            strmDataType.writeInt(iData[i]);
            strmDataType.writeUTF(sData[i]);

            // Clear any buffered data
            strmDataType.flush();

            // Get stream data into byte array and write record
            record = strmBytes.toByteArray();            
            _rs.addRecord(record, 0, record.length);           

            // Toss any data in the internal array so writes
            // starts at beginning (of the internal array)
            strmBytes.reset();
         }

         strmBytes.close();
         strmDataType.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   /** read in all the records, and print them out */
   public void readRecords()
   {
      try
      {
         RecordEnumeration re = _rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);         
         while (re.hasNextElement())
         {    
            // Get next record
            byte[] recData = re.nextRecord(); 

            // Read from the specified byte array
            ByteArrayInputStream strmBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(recData);

            // Read Java data types from the above byte array
            DataInputStream strmDataType = new DataInputStream(strmBytes);

            // Read back the data types
            System.out.println("Record ID=" + strmDataType.readInt());
            System.out.println("Boolean: " + strmDataType.readBoolean());
            System.out.println("Integer: " + strmDataType.readInt());
            System.out.println("String: " + strmDataType.readUTF());
            System.out.println("--------------------");

            strmBytes.close();
            strmDataType.close();        
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Here, I make use of a couple small `RecordFilter` classes, to use when searching the record store:

```
   /** helps filter out records greater than a certain id */
   private class IdGreaterThanFilter implements RecordFilter {
      private int _minimumId; 
      public IdGreaterThanFilter(int value) {
         _minimumId = value;
      }
      public boolean matches(byte[] candidate) {
         // return true if candidate record's id is greater than minimum value
         return (getIdFromRecord(candidate) > _minimumId);         
      }      
   }

   /** helps filter out records by id field (not "recordId"!) */
   private class IdEqualToFilter implements RecordFilter {
      private int _id; 
      public IdEqualToFilter(int value) {
         _id = value;
      }
      public boolean matches(byte[] candidate) {
         // return true if candidate record's id matches
         return (getIdFromRecord(candidate) == _id);         
      }      
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice & detail answer :) :D. But in that I doesn't understood code of following methods - `private static final void putIdIntoRecord(int id, byte[] record)` & `private static final int getIdFromRecord(byte[] record)` What exactly does that??? plz can you explain....

Comment: Those two methods are just for writing (`putIdIntoRecord()`) and reading (`getIdFromRecord()`) the new id field from your record.  If you look at the `writeRecords()` method, you'll see that I add this new `id` field as the first field to be written.  It is an `int` field, so it takes up 4 bytes.  In other places in the code, you'll see that I need to read the `id` value of a record, so I created a method to do that, without having to read the whole record (by creating an `InputStream`).  Similarly, after you delete a record, you want to update the `id` of other records -> `putIdIntoRecord()`.

Comment: @Rahul, note that I had a cut and paste error in `putIdIntoRecord()`, that I didn't notice, because I tested this code with a small number of records.  Please see my updated answer for the fixed version.  Thanks.